# webhdfs create using kerberos rest template HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, spring, rest, kerberos, webhdfs

I am trying to create a file in hdfs using webhdfs. Kerberos is used for security on cluster, so I use `KerberosRestTemplate`.

In my controller I have 2 methods

```
  @RequestMapping("/showFileContent")
  public ResponseEntity<String> showContent() throws URISyntaxException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(taxonService.getTaxonJSON(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @RequestMapping("/createFile")
  public ResponseEntity<URI> createFile() throws URISyntaxException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(taxonService.createFile(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

And in my service class I have

```
  public String getTaxonJSON() throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(path + "?op=OPEN");
    String json = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    return json;
  }

  public URI createFile() throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(path + "?op=CREATE");
    return restTemplate.postForLocation(uri, String.class);
  }
```

I can see file content just fine using `/showFileContent`, but every time I try `/createFile`, I get `Error running rest call; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error`. I remove the file before calling create.

What is the reason for the error?

Comment: Maybe the NameNode is just stalled. I have seen cases where the NN appeared to be OK at the core (RPC used by Java API) but its web server component was KO... If that's the case the only cure is a service restart. If you have a HA cluster, force failover to the other NN and try again, to see how that second NN reacts.

Comment: Anyway, the "internal" error must show in the log files of the NN service, in detail. That's the first thing to inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write to a file, not create one. This is enough for my needs and might help someone else, so I'll post it here.

```
public boolean writeFile(File file) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(path + "?op=CREATE" + "&overwrite=true&data=true");
    ResponseEntity e =kerberosRestTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<Resource>(new FileSystemResource(file)), Map.class);
    return e.getStatusCodeValue() == 201;
  }
```